# Customizing the output of Perforce RCS keyword expansion

Tags: perforce, rcs

I'd like to filter files using RCS keyword expansion so that instances of `$Change$` are translated to `1745` rather than the default behaviour of `$Change: 1745 $`.  I realize that this would prevent future expansions, but that's acceptable for the purposes.

Other methods of inserting the changelist number into a file are also welcome.  This is the only method I've seen with Perforce that works during submission -- it's just that I'd like to clean it up so that it can be cleanly inserted into version numbers.  Could this also be accomplished with triggers?

Comment: I am curious about this, too. I have a build wrapper script that edits a particular file locally, but this is inelegant at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for cannot be done with triggers. The only [triggers](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/cmdref/triggers.html#1040665) that are active during submit are `change-submit`, `change-content` and `change-commit`. You can only retrieve the file-content for the latter two, but with the `change-content` trigger, the changelist number is not yet fix, and with the `change-commit` trigger, the file-content is already committed and can't be changed. What's worse, though, is that you wouldn't have a way to submit a changed file-content back to the server from within your trigger.

The RCS keyword expansion works because it is done by the server itself and because Perforce does a refresh-after-submit, i.e. the client refreshes all files of a submitted change from the Perforce server, thereby getting the content with expanded RCS keywords.